# Adjusting the Contact selection display (e.g. New Contribution)

Tags: contacts

When adding a new contribution (as well as a few other places, I believe) we have the option to auto-complete a contact's name or create a new contact:

[image: Select contact options]

When we begin typing, a list of contacts appears, including email addresses if they have one:

[image: Type contact name]

Is there a way we can adjust this display to show different/additional information? For example, we may want to show city in small writing like the email address currently shows:

> Adams, Daren
>
> darena55@hotmail.co.in (Bangalore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, from the menu:

*Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Search Preferences.*

The setting to adjust is **Autocomplete Contact Search**.  There are a number of choices you could include.  This doesn't impact the field in question only though.  The biggest additional impact would be the Quick Search.  Note the help text:

> Selected fields will be displayed in back-office autocomplete dropdown
>   search results (Quick Search, etc.). Contact Name is always included.

---

The next option down on Search Preferences (Contact Reference Options) may come into play for certain fields as well.  Its help text:

> Selected fields will be displayed in autocomplete dropdown search results for 'Contact Reference' custom fields. Contact Name is always included.